# Should I allow or disallow robot to crawl GWT cache files such as '*cache.js'?

Tags: gwt, web-crawler

I have a GWT (Google Web Toolkit) application and some files (cache.js, nocache.js...) are generated under the **war/my_project** directory. I am using a robots.txt file and I have put :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my_project/
```

So is ok ? I mean, I want to be sure that it will not block robots to crawl urls of my website... I have just a doubt, even if I have tried via webmaster tool and I confirm that the robot can crawl my urls.

My question is that, I was asking myself, how the robot could crawl my url, if it does not have access to the source code generating theses urls (the application itself, so the *cache.js and *nocache.js) ?

thanks you,
Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the crawlers still dont use javascript. They see nothing of your GWT.
If they crawled the *.js, they would only index the source code, not the result, which you probably dont want.

In order for your website to be well indexable, you have to ensure the contents of the page are visible even with javascript turned off. This can be very annoying, and in some case's involve needing to use php or some server-side system to "burn out" copies of your pages.

If you use HistoryTokens, You might also need to look into the use of "#!" (hashbang) and "_escape_fragments_" in order to correctly link between static/generated webpages the crawlers can see, and the dynamic gwt equivalents you want them to link too.

Unfortunately, this is all a big rabbit hole.

Comment: Thanks you. I use webmaster tool and "Fetch as Google" has been successfully done. Indeed, I can click on the fetched url and see my page corectly. But there is also a way to see this page in "text mode" and here, I do not understand why I just have my HTML home page showing... I would like to see "textually" all the dynamic content generated instead of the simple <script src="MS/MS.nocache.js"></script>. Do you know if it is normal or if their is a problem with the crawl (I use #!, and Google Web Toolkit) ?

Comment: A GWT page/application is typically generated using javascript. The browser downloads the javascript and executes it. The execution of the javascript generates the page. A web crawler downloads the HTML and may downlaod the javascript. It won't see the page unless it executes the javascript - which typically is not what happens. One solution is to create HTML snapshots of your website purely for crawling. This is described [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)